# Why if/else for retrieved mongodb data is not working in Jade view

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

In my Jade view I have "raw" which contains retrieved mongodb data which I have passed to my jade view by res.render('jadeview',{raw:mongodbdata})

```
 body
.container
  h1 View Requests Page
  table
   tbody
    tr
     th ID
     th Request's
     th Description
     th Current Status            
    - if(raw.length)
        each item in raw
          tr
            td 
             a(href='/individualrequest/#{item._id}', id="idanch") #{item._id}
            td 
             a(href='/individualrequest/#{item._id}', id="rqstanch") #{item.request}
            td
             a(href='/individualrequest/#{item._id}', id="descanch") #{item.description}
            td 
            -if( #{item.approval} === 'true')
                    p Approved
             else
                  p Rejected
```

But for last td where I am comparing one of the retrieved value of "raw" with if else statements, I'm getting error as "500 Unexpected character '#'" , I've tried without #{item.approval} instead , I compared 'true' === 'true', then its working fine, I'm getting the output in the Jade View Page, but Why it is not taking #{item.approval}, if I give only td #{item.approval}, I'm getting the value, but not with if/else, please help me on this

Comment: I think it should be just `- if(item.approval === 'true')`, because you dont interpolate `item.approval` at that stage, in fact if its proper `boolean` you should do `- if(item.approval)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- if(item.approval)
```

should just work, no need to convert it to string, then compare to another string